# Can not populate database through servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I have created a jsp form and a servlet to populate database in mysql using tomcat, but when I hit 'Submit' button to pass values to database, it shows the message that 0 rows have been affected in the table. In server log, it shows the null pointer exception. I have added MySQL JDBC driver as well as JSTL 1.2.2 to libraries. 
I have created two excluded java classes for establishing db connection and to executing the queries.

Here is the servelet code:

```
public class SubmitUser extends HttpServlet {

private DbUpdate dbup = new DbUpdate(); 


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String profession = request.getParameter("profession");
    String features = request.getParameter("features");

    String sql = "INSERT INTO test values('profession','features')";
    int i = dbup.insertValues(sql);
```

Here is the DbUpdate.java file which contains the query execution

```
public class DbUpdate {

    private Statement st;
    private int i;
    private Connection c;

    private DbConnection dbcon = new DbConnection();


    public int insertValues(String sql){
        try {
            c = dbcon.connectDB();

            Statement st = c.createStatement();
            System.out.println("connected");
            i = st.executeUpdate(sql);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return i;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        //DbConnection dbcon =new DbConnection();
        //dbcon.connectDB();
        DbUpdate dbup = new DbUpdate();


    }

}
```

Finally the DbConnection.java file which establish the connection

```
public class DbConnection {

    private String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/online_feedback";
    private Connection con = null;
    private Statement st;
    //private int i;


    public Connection connectDB(){
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
            System.out.println("Conn obj :::" + con);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return con;
    }


    public static void main (String []args){

        DbConnection db = new DbConnection();
        db.connectDB();
    }

}
```

I can't figure out what has gone wrong

Thanks in advance

This is what I get in Servlet log

```html
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SubmitUser] in context with path [/Feedback] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at feedback.DbUpdate.insertValues(DbUpdate.java:32)
 at feedback.SubmitUser.processRequest(SubmitUser.java:76)
 at feedback.SubmitUser.doGet(SubmitUser.java:120)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The sql query you have written is wrong.

Comment: Please show the NullPointerException stacktrace.

Comment: You don't need `public static void main()` in each class. As they are not being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have some kind of duplicate key check. Your query should really use bind parameters, but your sql could be fixed like

```
// String sql = "INSERT INTO test values('profession','features')";
String sql = "INSERT INTO test values('" + profession + "','"
    + features + "')";
```

At the moment you are inserting the constants *profession* and *features*.

With a `PreparedStatement`, it might look more like

```
public int insertValues(String profession, String features) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO test values(?, ?)";
    Connection conn;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    try {
        conn = dbcon.connectDB();

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, profession);
        ps.setString(2, features);
        return ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                null, ex);
    } finally {
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The sql was definitely weird, but would not have caused the NullPointerException that is the root cause of this problem.

Comment: I have tried it with using prepared statements and all the other relevant changes, but still I am getting http 500 error with null pointer exception :(

Comment: @Suchini Then your Connection is probably `null`. Look into how you're connecting.